# Encoding equals symbol to html equivalent php

Tags: php, html, encode

I attempted encoding a '=' symbol to its html equivalent through the use of:

```
htmlentities("This is my test and it = this");
```

The result is:

```
&lt;p&gt;This is my test and it = this&lt;/p&gt;1
```

Notice how the equals sign is not encoded? I know there is a HTML equivalent.
What is an alternative function I can use to encode this string?

Thanks.

Comment: The example given is incorrect (there are no HTML tags in the argument passed). The question claims that there is an HTML equivalent but does not say what it is, and it does not say what “encoding” should be performed (or why).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know there is a HTML equivalent

The equals sign isn't encoded for HTML, there is no reason to do so.

You might be thinking of *URL*-encoding, which would be `%3d`:

```
urlencode("This is my test and it = this");
// => "This+is+my+test+and+it+%3D+this"
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to encode the `=`; it's HTML-safe. If you really want to, though: `&#61;`

```
echo str_replace('=', '&#61;', htmlentities("This is my test and it = this"));
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/AiwQf3)